# Is there any way to get radiotypes of wlan adapter using WinPcap?

Tags: winpcap, wifi

I am developing a sniffer using WinPcap. Is there any API to get the information like RadioType (i.e 802.11a/b/g/n) and frequency band of it?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with WinPcap only with [an AirPcap adapter](http://www.riverbed.com/products/performance-management-control/network-performance-management/wireless-packet-capture.html); WinPcap doesn't support "monitor mode" capture with regular 802.11 adapters.